# What programming language do I learn if I want to become artificial intelligence engineer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, algorithm, superintelligence, programming-languages

I would become artificial intelligence engineer in the future, so I want to start programming but I don't know what programming language I start for that.

Comment: Hi Mamadou, I understand that starting something can be challenging, and thank you for your question. I would rephrase it to, "What programming language has the biggest community support and documentation for designing AI models and algos?". This is because practically any language can be used to design and train AI models. In answer, I think it will benefit you to start learning python for the same cause.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Python is a great programming language to start with if you're interested in becoming an AI engineer. It's widely used in the field of AI and machine learning due to its simplicity and large community support. It also has numerous libraries and frameworks like TensorFlow, Keras, PyTorch, and Scikit-learn that are specifically designed for AI and machine learning.

After you're comfortable with Python, you might want to learn other languages that are commonly used in AI like Java, C++, and R. However, Python is definitely a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Any language will do. Most differences are just in the syntax and the idioms of a particular language, but you can usually pick up a new language fairly quickly.

Having said that, there are some languages that are more common in certain areas. *Python* seems to be quite popular in a lot of modern AI work. I myself work in natural language processing, and the company I'm at uses *Lisp*.

My suggestion would be to start with some easier languages, and keeping an open mind about learning about other languages. The more you know, the easier it is to switch between them and to learn new ones.